# Page Refresh with out disturbing content on Button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to refresh my page on `Image Button` click with out disturbing the page content can any one give me a proper script or code. I don't want to use `AJAX`

I tried this but didn't work

```
<script>
function Reload()
{
 window.opener.location.reload(); 
}
</script>

<asp:imagebutton id="img1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ReLoad();"></asp:imagebutton>
```

So can any one help me with proper script

Comment: What do you mean by "disturbing". If you mean the occasional flash at reload this cannot be fixed afaik - it's just happening because the CSS is refreshed not fast enough.

Comment: `Thomas` disturbing in the sense my page will have some values, those values should not be cleared

Comment: Reloading a site without losing values entered in a form (if thats what you mean) is not possbile. I think you should look into AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean having asynchronous update, so that only the relevant part of the page is updated when the user clicks the button? check out `asp:UpdatePanel`. There is an easy overview of this stuff here: [Ajax.Net Tutorial](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/)

Comment: `Oliver` with out `AJAX` i would like to do